# Mint Cinnamon 18.3 64 bit Update problem

Tags: linux-mint

When I run the update manager for Linux Mint Cinnamon 18.30 I get the following error and don't know how to fix.

```
E: gcc-6-base: 1.0989:package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should  reinstall it before attempting configuration
E: libgcc1: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libc6: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: liblzma5: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libxau6: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libxdmcp6: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libxcb1: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libx11-6: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libxext6: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libexif12: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libjpeg-turbo8: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: liblcms2-2: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libxdamage1: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libxfixes3: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libxshmfence1: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libxxf86vm1: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libasound2: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libdrm2: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libexpat1: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libglapi-mesa: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libx11-xcb1: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libxcb-dri2-0: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libxcb-dri3-0: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libxcb-glx0: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libxcb-present0: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libxcb-sync1: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libdrm-amdgpu1: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: zlib1g: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libpciaccess0: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libdrm-intel1: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libdrm-nouveau2: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libdrm-radeon1: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libelf1: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libbsd0: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libtinfo5: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libedit2: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libffi6: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libstdc++6: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libllvm5.0: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libsensors4: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libgl1-mesa-dri: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libgl1-mesa-glx: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libglu1-mesa: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libpng12-0: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libfreetype6: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libfontconfig1: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libjpeg8: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libjbig0: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libtiff5: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libvpx3: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libxpm4: 1.0989:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Answer (score 0):

As given in first line

> E: gcc-6-base: 1.0989:package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting configuration

You must have to reinstall that package.
Use code

```
apt-cache search gcc
```

then

```
apt-get update

apt-get install g++-(version) c++-(version)
```

You can use any version(I recommend you 4+)
If the repository was not found then use this and again try those codes listed above

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

Run these codes in your terminal

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/mintinstall.postinst
```

then
`sudo apt install -f`
and comment the output